# How to call a generic extension method dynamically?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I wrote this extension method:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
{...}
```

It works well if called with a type known at compile time:

```
DataTable tbl = new List<int>().ToDataTable();
```

But how to call it if the generic type isn't known?

```
object list = new List<int>();
...
tbl = Extension.ToDataTable((List<object>)list); // won't work
```

Comment: Why do you cast to `List<object>`? Your `list` is a `List<int>`, the cast won't succeed.

Comment: Because he doesn't know at compile time what type of list he's got: he doesn't know it's `List<int>`.  He's trying to get around it by casting to a base class (which, as you rightly note, won't work because `List<int>` isn't compatible with `List<object>` even though `int` is compatible with `object`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This occurs because a `List<int>` is not a `List<object>` -- the List type is not covariant in its element type parameter.  Unfortunately you would need to get a typed version of the generic method and call it using reflection:

```
Type listItemType = typeof(int);   // cheating for simplicity - see below for real approach
MethodInfo openMethod = typeof(Extension).GetMethod("ToDataTable", ...);
MethodInfo typedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(listItemType));
typedMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { list });
```

An alternative may be to create a version of your extension method that accepts `IList` rather than `IList<T>`.  The `List<T>` class implements this non-generic interface as well as the generic interface, so you will be able to call:

```
public static DataTable WeakToDataTable(this IList list) { ... }

((IList)list).WeakToDataTable();
```

(In reality you'd probably use an overload rather than a different name -- just using a different name to call out the different types.)

---

**More info:** In the reflection solution, I skipped over the problem of how to determine the list element type.  This can be a bit tricky depending on how sophisticated you want to get.  If you're assuming that the object will be a `List<T>` (for some T) then it's easy:

```
Type listItemType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

If you're only willing to assume `IList<T>` then it's a bit harder, because you need to locate the appropriate interface and get the generic argument from that.  And you can't use GetInterface() because you're looking for a closed constructed instance of a generic interface.  So you have to grovel through all the interfaces looking for one which is an instance of `IList<T>`:

```
foreach (Type itf in list.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
  if (itf.IsGenericType && itf.GetGenericTypeDefinition == typeof(IList<>))  // note generic type definition syntax
  {
    listItemType = itf.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  }
}
```

This will work for empty lists because it goes off the metadata, not the list content.

Comment: Would not just casting to `List<int>` instead of `List<object>` solve the problem?

Comment: Sure, but the question asks "how to call it **if the generic type isn't known**?" (emphasis added).  Hence my note that in reality he'd also have to figure out the listItemType using reflection rather than just assuming it's int.

Comment: I tried this, but I have two problems: 1. How will I get the type of the embedded elements if the list is empty? 2. I have two ToDataTable() extension methods. How to get the one for IList<T>?

Comment: Alex: From your answer, it looks like you've gone for the non-generic `IList` solution and solved the problem using overloads, so I'm guessing you no longer need answers to these two questions -- leave another comment if you do.

Comment: @itowlson: I haven't a problem any more but I'm interested in the answers. That is the reason I haven't closed the question already. :) It's your choice.

Comment: alex: I've updated the answer to answer your first question.  Not sure about your second question -- what extension methods are you trying to distinguish between?

Answer (score 0):

After having trouble to get it working with the `IList<T>` interface I solved it using the `IList` interface like [itowlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61700/itowlson) proposed. It's a little bit ugly because of the _T method but it works well:

```
DataTable tbl = ((IList)value).ToDataTable();

public static class Extensions
{
    private static DataTable ToDataTable(Array array) {...}
    private static DataTable ToDataTable(ArrayList list) {...}
    private static DataTable ToDataTable_T(IList list) {...}

    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IList list)
    {
        if (list.GetType().IsArray)
        {
            // handle arrays - int[], double[,] etc.
            return ToDataTable((Array)list);
        }
        else if (list.GetType().IsGenericType)
        {
            // handle generic lists - List<T> etc.
            return ToDataTable_T(list);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle non generic lists - ArrayList etc.
            return ToDataTable((ArrayList)list);
        }            
    }
}
```